# How to install Django 1.4 with Python 3.2.3 in Debian?

Tags: python, django, debian

I installed Python 3.2.3 in Debian /usr/local/bin/python3 and I installed Django 1.4 in the same directory. But when I try to import django from python 3 shell interpreter I get syntax error! What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no official release of Django that does it, but the guys [here](https://bitbucket.org/loewis/django-3k/) on bitbucket have been working on a port to python 3.  Django will officially support python3 experimentally with version 1.5

Answer (score 3):

Django does not support Python 3.  You will need to install a version of Python 2.x.

Comment: Really? Thank you for the info. Are they developing Django for Python3?